# Calculate XPath of an html element without attributes

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="search-page-right-pannel">

<div class="search-page-heading-red" style="font-weight:400; margin-bottom:7px; margin-top:-4px; text-align:left">

Big Bazaar (Future Group) <b>(Future)</b> </div>
    <img src="images/address-icon.png" alt="" />&nbsp; Knowledge House, Shyam Nagar Off Jogeshwari-Vikhroli Link Road                                 Jogeshwari (East)<br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mumbai                    Maharashtra , 400060    <div class="detail-line"><img src="images/call.png" alt="" /> (022) 30841300  66442200  61190000<!--<span onmouseover="TagToTip('Span2')" onmouseout="UnTip()"><img src="images/call.png" alt="" /> <u style="color: #3079af">click to view number</u></span>-->
  <img src="images/website-icon.png" alt="" style="margin-left:80px;" /> <a href="http://www.bigbazaar.com" target="_blank" class="pglink">www.bigbazaar.com</a> <span style="float:right"> </span>
 </div>
```

I Want the XPath of

> Knowledge House, Shyam Nagar Off Jogeshwari-Vikhroli Link Road    Jogeshwari (East)
>         Mumbai    Maharashtra , 400060

and also separate the elements of phone_no and website

> (022) 30841300 66442200 61190000   www.bigbazaar.com

Comment: Sounds like you don't want the XPath of an html element at all; you want the XPath of some text nodes (that are children of HTML elements). What XPath expressions have you tried, and what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

You could try an XPath expression like:

```
//div[@class='search-page-right-pannel']/text()[3]
```

- The word `pannel` looks like a typo, but I don't know whether it's actually spelled that way on the web page you're working with.
- This will get you the third text node child of the specified div element. That may be the wrong number, depending on whitespace processing. You could try `[1]` or `[2]` instead of `[3]`, but either way it'll be fragile. Less fragile would be to take advantage of the img element:

.

```
//div[@class='search-page-right-pannel']/img[@src='images/address-icon.png']/
   following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Similarly, the phone number could be selected using

```xml
//div[@class='search-page-right-pannel']/img[@src='images/call.png']/
   following-sibling::text()[1]
```

and the domain name:

```xml
//div[@class='search-page-right-pannel']/a[@class='pglink']/text()
```

Take a look at how these expressions work. I'd rather help you learn how to fish than just give you a fish. Let me know if you have questions.